# How to catch any exception but a group of exceptions in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

What might be a pythonic way of capturing all exceptions except for a few like `SyntaxError` or `AssertionError` which you'd want to always go uncaught?

Motivation being that we want to iterate a huge number of input files, and use `try` to gracefully go on when just one or few files fail to be processed. Catching `SyntaxError`, `AssertionError` and such would be too much to continue running after, as they imply a level of code breakage much higher than anything we'd want to forgo.

At a deeper level, is there beyond python 3's Exception hierarchy, any existing grouping of exceptions that better differentiates exception types? I do not find the given hierarchy extremely sensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
try:
    # do some stuff here
except SyntaxError:
    # do not catch this one
    raise
except AssertionError:
    # do not catch this one
    raise
except Exception:
    # catch all the others
```

Answer (score 1):

What about catching the exceptions broadly and then check if the caught exception is what you want to catch.

```
enter code here
try:
    #code
except Exception:
    if Exception == AssertionError:
        # do smthg
    elseif Exception == SyntaxError:
        # do smthg
    else:
        return
```

Comment: I'm not expecting a specific one, rather, I would like to hedge for when my code runs on target environments for the first time, without allowing it to fail on "too simple stuff". But thanks!